# cmd and exclamation marks

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, delayedvariableexpansion

the following code fails for folder names containing exclamation marks. I think I need DelayedExpansion enabled to handle the nested for loops. Any ideas to get this work? Thanks!

```
@echo off & setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "dest=%~dpn1"
IF "%1" equ "" Set "dest=%cd%"

set /a Folders=0
set /a FoldersWithSubFoldersAndFiles=0
set /a FoldersWithOnlyFiles=0
set /a FoldersWithOnlySubFolders=0
set /a FoldersEmpty=0

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`DIR /AD /S /B "%dest%"`) do (
    Set /a Folders+=1
    for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`DIR "%%a" /A-D /B 2^>NUL^| FIND /C /V ""`) do (
        Set NumberOfFiles=%%i
    )
    for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`DIR "%%a" /AD /B 2^>NUL^| FIND /C /V ""`) do (
        set NumberOfFolders=%%i
    )
    IF "!NumberOfFiles!" neq "0" IF "!NumberOfFolders!" neq "0" set /a FoldersWithSubFoldersAndFiles+=1
    IF "!NumberOfFiles!" neq "0" IF "!NumberOfFolders!" equ "0" set /a FoldersWithOnlyFiles+=1
    IF "!NumberOfFiles!" equ "0" IF "!NumberOfFolders!" neq "0" set /a FoldersWithOnlySubFolders+=1
    IF "!NumberOfFiles!" equ "0" IF "!NumberOfFolders!" equ "0" (
        set /a FoldersEmpty+=1
        echo %%a is empty.
    )
)

echo Found %Folders% folders below "%dest%".
echo %FoldersWithSubFoldersAndFiles% folders containing files and subfolders.
echo %FoldersWithOnlyFiles% folders containing files only.
echo %FoldersWithOnlySubFolders% folders containing subfolders only.
echo %FoldersEmpty% folders are empty.

endlocal
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see 3 simple solutions:

1) The slowest method is to use CALL so that you do not need delayed expansion within your loop.

```
@echo off & setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

set "dest=%~dpn1"
IF "%1" equ "" Set "dest=%cd%"

set /a Folders=0
set /a FoldersWithSubFoldersAndFiles=0
set /a FoldersWithOnlyFiles=0
set /a FoldersWithOnlySubFolders=0
set /a FoldersEmpty=0

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`DIR /AD /S /B "%dest%"`) do (
    Set /a Folders+=1
    for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`DIR "%%a" /A-D /B 2^>NUL^| FIND /C /V ""`) do (
        Set NumberOfFiles=%%i
    )
    for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`DIR "%%a" /AD /B 2^>NUL^| FIND /C /V ""`) do (
        set NumberOfFolders=%%i
    )
    call :incrementCounts
)

echo Found %Folders% folders below "%dest%".
echo %FoldersWithSubFoldersAndFiles% folders containing files and subfolders.
echo %FoldersWithOnlyFiles% folders containing files only.
echo %FoldersWithOnlySubFolders% folders containing subfolders only.
echo %FoldersEmpty% folders are empty.
echo See dircount.log for list of empty folders.

endlocal
exit /b

:incrementCounts
IF "%NumberOfFiles%" neq "0" IF "%NumberOfFolders%" neq "0" set /a FoldersWithSubFoldersAndFiles+=1
IF "%NumberOfFiles%" neq "0" IF "%NumberOfFolders%" equ "0" set /a FoldersWithOnlyFiles+=1
IF "%NumberOfFiles%" equ "0" IF "%NumberOfFolders%" neq "0" set /a FoldersWithOnlySubFolders+=1
IF "%NumberOfFiles%" equ "0" IF "%NumberOfFolders%" equ "0" (
    set /a FoldersEmpty+=1
    echo %%a is empty.
)
exit /b
```

2) A faster method is to temporarily enable delayed expansion only long enough to transfer the values to FOR variables.

```
@echo off & setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

set "dest=%~dpn1"
IF "%1" equ "" Set "dest=%cd%"

set /a Folders=0
set /a FoldersWithSubFoldersAndFiles=0
set /a FoldersWithOnlyFiles=0
set /a FoldersWithOnlySubFolders=0
set /a FoldersEmpty=0

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`DIR /AD /S /B "%dest%"`) do (
    Set /a Folders+=1
    for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`DIR "%%a" /A-D /B 2^>NUL^| FIND /C /V ""`) do (
        Set NumberOfFiles=%%i
    )
    for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`DIR "%%a" /AD /B 2^>NUL^| FIND /C /V ""`) do (
        set NumberOfFolders=%%i
    )
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    for /f "tokens=1,2" %%N in ("!NumberOfFiles! !NumberOfFolders!") do (
        endlocal
        IF "%%N" neq "0" IF "%%M" neq "0" set /a FoldersWithSubFoldersAndFiles+=1
        IF "%%N" neq "0" IF "%%M" equ "0" set /a FoldersWithOnlyFiles+=1
        IF "%%N" equ "0" IF "%%M" neq "0" set /a FoldersWithOnlySubFolders+=1
        IF "%%N" equ "0" IF "%%M" equ "0" (
            set /a FoldersEmpty+=1
            echo %%a is empty.
        )
    )
)

echo Found %Folders% folders below "%dest%".
echo %FoldersWithSubFoldersAndFiles% folders containing files and subfolders.
echo %FoldersWithOnlyFiles% folders containing files only.
echo %FoldersWithOnlySubFolders% folders containing subfolders only.
echo %FoldersEmpty% folders are empty.
echo See dircount.log for list of empty folders.

endlocal
```

3) But the way I would handle it is to eliminate the 2 variables that are only used within the loop. They aren't used outside the loop, and they are already derived from FOR variables. Since everything is now a FOR variable, you no longer need delayed expansion.

```
@echo off & setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "dest=%~dpn1"
IF "%1" equ "" Set "dest=%cd%"

set /a Folders=0
set /a FoldersWithSubFoldersAndFiles=0
set /a FoldersWithOnlyFiles=0
set /a FoldersWithOnlySubFolders=0
set /a FoldersEmpty=0

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`DIR /AD /S /B "%dest%"`) do (
    Set /a Folders+=1
    for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%N in (`DIR "%%a" /A-D /B 2^>NUL^| FIND /C /V ""`) do (
        for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%M in (`DIR "%%a" /AD /B 2^>NUL^| FIND /C /V ""`) do (
            IF "%%N" neq "0" IF "%%M" neq "0" set /a FoldersWithSubFoldersAndFiles+=1
            IF "%%N" neq "0" IF "%%M" equ "0" set /a FoldersWithOnlyFiles+=1
            IF "%%N" equ "0" IF "%%M" neq "0" set /a FoldersWithOnlySubFolders+=1
            IF "%%N" equ "0" IF "%%M" equ "0" (
                set /a FoldersEmpty+=1
                echo %%a is empty.
            )
        )
    )
)

echo Found %Folders% folders below "%dest%".
echo %FoldersWithSubFoldersAndFiles% folders containing files and subfolders.
echo %FoldersWithOnlyFiles% folders containing files only.
echo %FoldersWithOnlySubFolders% folders containing subfolders only.
echo %FoldersEmpty% folders are empty.
echo See dircount.log for list of empty folders.

endlocal
```

Comment: Whow! Thanks a lot! I think I like all three variants - and learned again more about cmd special handling :-). But with DelayedExpansion completely disabled: Will then an ampersand in folder names not break the script? Nevertheless: I will try it and report tomorrow. Night already started here... Martin

Comment: @CmdQuestion - Ampersands in file or folder names should not cause any problems with any of the options.

Comment: Works! Nice procedure now :-) Martin